# Display the same data in two different places in Modx

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, modx

I'm new to Modx but already have some experience with chunks and snippets. Still, I don't really know the best way to display the same type of resource in two different places in modx.

On my site I have "review" resources which I want to have in a slider on main page ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkZs3.jpg)) and on a dedicated reviews page ([like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcgpz.png)) with them being the same resources.

What's the best approach to solving this? Should I use Extras for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [getResources](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources) extra, in fact 99.99% of all modx sites you develop will probably use getResources.

Basically it allows yo to grab the attributes [content, TVs, title, alias etc] of a given gresource or set of resources [that you can search and filter with the getResources call!] and display them in different types of views by defining a chunk to use as a tpl for your content.

I use it for almost every carousel I have ever implemented [in modx]

Comment: `> 99.99%` - other half used http://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources (part of pdotools)

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this.